# Missing C library header, map.h, in Mac OS X 10.9.2

Tags: c, makefile, osx-mavericks

When I try to make [this C-project](https://code.google.com/p/vtr-verilog-to-routing/) on Mac OS X 10.9, I get the following error from the compiler:

```
gcc -I../libarchfpga/include -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-qual -D__USE_FIXED_PROTOTYPES__ -ansi -pedantic -Wshadow -Wcast-align -D_POSIX_SOURCE -Wno-write-strings -D EZXML_NOMMAP -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE -O3 -DNO_GRAPHICS -MD -MP -I-ISRC/util -ISRC/timing -ISRC/pack -ISRC/place -ISRC/base -ISRC/route -ISRC/power -I../printhandler/SRC/TIO_InputOutputHandlers -ISRC/util -c SRC/route/croute_directed_search.c -o OBJ/route/croute_directed_search.o
In file included from SRC/route/croute_directed_search.c:5:
SRC/base/vpr_types.h:37:10: fatal error: 'map' file not found
#include <map>
         ^
```

I tried to to find map.h via the following command

```
find / -iname "map.h"
```

and I got the following results

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/map.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/debug/map.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/map.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/debug/map.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/map.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/debug/map.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/map.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/debug/map.h
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/scipy/weave/blitz/blitz/array/map.h
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/scipy/weave/blitz/blitz/array/map.h
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/map.h
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/debug/map.h
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: `<map>` isn’t a C header, it’s a C++ header; why is it being included by a C source file?

Comment: Yeah, despite this having .C extensions this is C++ code.  The .C extension is probably confusing your compiler.  I'd be complaining to the owners of that code that that's really confusing not to mention preventing building.

Comment: eavsteen, perhaps you should elaborate further on why it is important to include map (or map.h) in the C code.  Is there a function defined in map.h that you need to implement in the C code?  Please edit the question and clarify why your C code needs to include this header.

Comment: Also, `<map>` is a file called `map`. Not `map.h`.

Comment: I took a look at the 'this C-project' [ https://code.google.com/p/vtr-verilog-to-routing/ ] (as indicated by the question).  It is a large project (overall).  I searched it (via grep) for all occurrences of the word 'map' which also have the word 'include' on the same line.  The search yielded the following .h file references: mapper.h, mapperInt.h and partial_map.h.  Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any reference to <map> or <map.h>.  Perhaps, the link supplied by the question is not the right code?

Comment: Indeed the project moved from gcc to g++.
I still used the old project's makefile.

Comment: You can find the include on line 37 of the following source file http://vtr-verilog-to-routing.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/vpr/SRC/base/vpr_types.h